# Complex number syntax error in C (using VScode)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, complex-numbers

I want to use Complex number in c (using VScode),but it doesn't work.

other c code without Complex number can compile & execute successfully,

I've included complex.h and set Cstandard as C99

here's my code & error message

```c
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <complex.h>    

int main() 
{
    double complex z1 = 1.0 + 3.0 * I;
    double complex z2 = 1.0 - 4.0 * I;

    printf(" values: Z1 = %.2f + %.2fi\tZ2 = %.2f + %.2fi\n", 
           creal(z1), 
           cimag(z1), 
           creal(z2), 
           cimag(z2));

    getchar();
}
```

error message:

```
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c: In function 'int main()':
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c:6:20: error: expected initializer before 'z1'
     double complex z1 = 1.0 + 3.0 * I;
                    ^~
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c:7:20: error: expected initializer before 'z2'
     double complex z2 = 1.0 - 4.0 * I;
                    ^~
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c:12:18: error: 'z1' was not declared in this scope
            creal(z1),
                  ^~
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c:12:18: note: suggested alternative: 'y1'
            creal(z1),
                  ^~
                  y1
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c:14:18: error: 'z2' was not declared in this scope
            creal(z2),
                  ^~
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: g++ -g c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c -o C:\grchen\C\code\dft.exe <

c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c: In function 'int main()':
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c:6:20: error: expected initializer before 'z1'
     double complex z1 = 1.0 + 3.0 * I;
                    ^~
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c:7:20: error: expected initializer before 'z2'
     double complex z2 = 1.0 - 4.0 * I;
                    ^~
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c:12:18: error: 'z1' was not declared in this scope
            creal(z1),
                  ^~
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c:12:18: note: suggested alternative: 'y1'
            creal(z1),
                  ^~
                  y1
c:\grchen\C\code\practice\dft.c:14:18: error: 'z2' was not declared in this scope
            creal(z2),
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/backward",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/tr1",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c99",
            "cppStandard": "c++98",
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/backward",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/tr1",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }

        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

[code&error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfVLw.png)
[properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brlZP.png)

Thanks for your time.

(I'm not native speaker,my English is pretty basic, please don't mind)

Comment: Looks like another VS non-compliance...

Comment: Does your compiler actually support C99's complex numbers?  Microsoft doesn't exactly have the best track record with C standards beyond C89.

Comment: @gtzkw What visual C++ has to do with the code above? It is clearly mingw

Comment: Try [`struct _complex z1 = {1.0, 3.0};`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/cabs?view=vs-2019) (I don't have Microsoft products to test this on)

Comment: @pmg The problem is I'm using g++ instead of gcc , so the announcement of my code doesn't work in C++,thank you very much anyway

Comment: Oh, ok @grchen. Thanks for the feedback. I'll leave the comment anyway: might be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're compiling it as C++ code, not C11.

I was able to compiler it with mingw64 on Windows 10, GCC v8.1, x64.

```
> gcc -std=c11 a.c
```

works and produce .exe which runs as expected

```
> g++ a.c
```

produce compilation errors like you stated. Compile it as C11 program and everything should be fine

Comment: Oh! It really is ,I didn't notice that I used g++ to compile ,appreciate your answer , have a nice day

Comment: @grchen You're welcome. It this answers your question, please accept it and lets move on